# Need help generating list with crunch

Tags: python, wordlist, crunch

I am new to Kali Linux.

I am trying to generate a wordlist of 6- whatever character words where:

- the first part is an English word that starts with a capital letter
- the last 5 characters are `8765.` It ends in a period

I've been trying for the last hour to make it work properly in `crunch` going through the man pages and threads. But I can't seem to be able to get it to work. My main issues are getting the dictionary list from GitHub, then making it start with a capital letter.

Ideally, it would be 9- 11 or 12 characters but I’m uninterested at this point in figuring out how to do that, I’ll do that another time. The problem there is using a dictionary list obviously they have 2 letter and longer letter words that using that ending would exclude 2 letter English words and perhaps truncate longer words.

Comment: Do you need to use `crunch`  specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with john's `--stdout` flag:

```
$ cat words.txt                                                           
ab
word
words
wordss
reallylongword


$ john --stdout --wordlist=words.txt --rules=:'c$8$7$6$5$.' --min-length=9 --max-length=12 > mywords.txt
[...]

$ cat mywords.txt 
Word8765.
Words8765.
Wordss8765.
```

You can either use one of the dictionaries include in Kali (such as the one @mti2935 suggested), or one you download. You can also set the minimum and maximum lengths to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty python script that uses the dictionary at `/usr/share/dict/american-english` (which is installed by default on Ubuntu and other distos) that might point you in the right direction:

```
dictionary='/usr/share/dict/american-english'
f=open(dictionary, 'r')
for line in f:
    out=line.strip()
    out=out.capitalize()
    out+='8765.'
    print(out)  
f.close()
```

This produces:

```
A8765.
A's8765.
Amd8765.
Amd's8765.
Aol8765.
Aol's8765.
Aws8765.
Aws's8765.
Aachen8765.
Aachen's8765.
[etc.]
```

To restrict the output to only strings of certain lengths, you can just put an `if` statement inside the loop with a condition based on `len(out)`