# Creating a custom wordlist for MS Word

Tags: password-cracking, wordlist

I have a Word document that is password protected. Am I wrong in assuming that if I know nothing about the password that it’s basically a waste of time trying to crack it?

I do remember it’s two short words put together.

My problem is I have no idea how to make a list of all those word combinations. I’ve tried using the English dictionary but it seems absurd to try to make a list of all English words, say, of length 5 or shorter, and put them together With shorter words to make a list. For example, "springegg" or "hotone".

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

There are approximately 50,000 words in the English language that are 5 characters or less.  If you are sure that your password was comprised of two English words that are each 5 characters or less, then that's a space of about 2.5 billion possible passwords (50,000 * 50,000 = 2.5 billion).

Programs like [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) and [John The Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) running on a modern desktop or laptop system can crack passwords in much larger spaces within a few days.  So, you might be in luck.

You'll need to construct a list of possible passwords to feed to one of the above programs - based on your knowledge that the password is comprised of two English words that are each 5 characters or less.  See [Need help generating list with crunch](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/261836/need-help-generating-list-with-crunch/) for a similar question involving the creation of a similar list.  Or, better yet, apply @nobody's suggestion below of using hashcat's combinator attack (ht, nobody).

Comment: That's going to be a somewhat large wordlist. Since it is luckily exactly two words, hashcat's [combinator attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=combinator_attack) should work better.

Comment: Thanks @nobody.  I wasn't aware that hashcat had such an option.  That's definitely better than constructing a list.

Comment: You could also do it with John's PRINCE mode and force it to use two elements `--prince=words.txt --prince-elem-cnt-min=2 --prince-elem-cnt-max=2`

Comment: Note that there are less than 8k _somewhat common_ words with 5 or fewer characters (going off a dictionary I've got with about 60k words, which includes ones as unusual as "abaft" but not too much more). Starting with those is much more reasonable.

Comment: Is it possible I can have that list of somewhat common words?

Comment: Do you have that list?

Comment: @Rgh001 See https://controlc.com/0f8833ac for a list of 7651 words extracted from /usr/share/dict/american-english which 1) are five or less characters in length, 2) do not contain the apostrophe symbol, 3) do not begin with an uppercase letter.